# How do I ensure Rails ActiveRecord sort order is applied when using Jquery .append?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a controller that returns a queryset like so;

```
def show
  @docs = Docs.where("id > ?", params[:id]).order(:id).reverse_order
  respond to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

In the rails console this returns my records in the correct order.

**show.js.erb** looks like this;

```
<% unless @docs.empty? %>
  $("#published").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@docs)) %>");
<% end %>
```

EDIT: I'm using a partial like so and I believe the order is ignored here;

my **index.html** calls;

```
<%= render @outline.outline_docs %>
```

which renders **outline\_outline_doc.html.erb **;

```
<div class="well" data-doc="<%= outline_doc.id %>">
  <h4><%= link_to outline_doc.id, "" %></h4>
  <%= Time.at(outline_doc.created_at.to_i + 1) %>
  </br>
</div>
```

But instead of the items being displayed in the order specified in the controller (27,28,29,30) they are always displayed as (28,29,27,30). Any ordering specified is always ignored.

How can I ensure that the records retrieved are appended in the desired manner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
def show
  @docs = Docs.where("id >", params[:id]).all
  @docs.sort! { |a,b| a.id <=> b.id }
  respond to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

The primary problem MAY be that the adapter that you use to connect to your DB does not respect ordering

EDIT: Responding to your comment:
Lets try moving the ordering to a view:

```
<% unless @docs.empty? %>
  $("#published").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(@docs.sort! { |a,b| a.id <=> b.id })) %>");
<% end %>
```

EDIT2: PARTIALS

try rendering your partial like this

```
<%= render :partial => @outline.outline_docs, :collection => @docs.sort! { |a,b| a.id <=> b.id } %>
```

Alternatively (if you are sure the order is passed correctly in your existing code) just:

```
<%= render :partial => @outline.outline_docs, :collection => @docs %>
```

I didn't see how your outline is directly connected with @docs so you may try using `:collections` with @docs (if the second render call is the culprit):

```
$("#published").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => "PARTIAL NAME", :collection => @docs)) %>");
<% end %>
```

Don't forget to replace PARTIAL NAME with whatever the partial you want to render @docs in or use @docs instead of PARTIAL NAME if you have corresponsing `to_partial_path`

Comment: I've tried that but the order is always the same. I'm sure it's not the adapter because I get the desired results in the console.

Comment: @ObregonCornsnook Edited with additional response, try it

Comment: Thanks. I tried it and noticed that the order is still ignored. Digging deeper I saw that just outputting the results simply gave me the correct order but because I'm using a partial (see edit above) the order is ignored. How do I keep the needed order while using the partial?

Comment: @ObregonCornsnook check EDIT2, maybe this will help in resolving the error, I am not able to test right now so sorry if I relegate it to you :)

Comment: This one did it...  `$("#published").append("<%=raw escape_javascript(render(:partial => "PARTIAL NAME", :collection => @docs)) %>");`  ... thanks for your help.